# Error in PSTricks in circuit macros

Tags: macros, pstricks

I am trying the same way to use circuit macros through the example from Mr. Peter Jan Randewijk (http://staff.ee.sun.ac.za/pjrandewijk/wiki/index.php/M4_Circuit_Macros). I have installed M4 support as well DPIC and circuit macros. First I had the same erros above. After that, I downloaded the last psstring package (http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) and the noCurrentValue passed and I got the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence \spline
```

I think I have done the correct way in installing pstrick package, altough I found few documentation about it. I am using Ubuntu 10.04.4.

The same way I have tried in windows 7 and it worked well. Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the answer given where you originally posted this question.  You have probably called dpic without the correct option (-p for PSTricks).  See the Quick Start section of the Circuit_macros manual.